# Bezier curve seems to be locked from moving on certain axis

Tags: bezier-curves

I am in 2.81 and created a bezier curve to act as a string in a scene. However, when I go to edit the curve, I grab the end point and attempt to move it on the x axis and it won't go that way. It will go on the z and the y but not the x.

I can go to object mode, rotate it to the right angle but that is not a very good work around.

I cannot find any place where I might have accidentally locked it.

Comment: Is your curve set to *2D*?

Comment: Yes. 2d, bevel depth to .028", Resolution 4. Does the Active Spline have anything to do with this?

Comment: If your curve is 2D then you can't move on the local Z axis.

Comment: Ah! okay thank you!